# vb.net search directory for files containing *.G(num) but NOT *.GP(num)

Tags: vb.net, search, copy, rename

I'm fairly familiar with bash, but I'm very, ***very**** new to vb.net.  I'm searching for an easy way to find files in a folder that end with .G1, .G2, .G3, etc.  but NOT .GP1, .GP2, .GP3, etc.  Then for each file I need to copy it to another folder using a different file name but the same extension.  I've managed to figure this out for the unique files, but there will be an undefined number of these depending on the project and I need to make sure that I get them all.  Hard coding is possible, but very, very ugly.  Any suggestions?

Here's the remnants of a failed attempt:

```
Public Sub FindGFiles()
   FileList = IO.Directory.GetFiles(searchDir, ".G[1-99]" + , IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
   For Each foundfile As String In FileList
        If foundfile.Contains(".G#") Then
            'copy file somehow and retain file extension
        Else
            MsgBox("No match")
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`GetFiles`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles)-method does only support `*` and `?` wildcard characters.
So you have to get all files with a `*.G*`-extension first.

In the `For Each`-loop one can then use the [`Like`-operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/like-operator) to check the desired pattern:

```
Public Sub CopyGFiles(searchDir As String, destDir As String)
    Dim fileList As String() = IO.Directory.GetFiles(searchDir, "*.G*", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim extension As String

    For Each foundfile As String In fileList
        fileName = IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(foundfile)
        extension = IO.Path.GetExtension(foundfile)

        If extension Like ".G#" OrElse
           extension Like ".G##" Then
            'copy file to destination, append "_new" to the filename and retain file extension
            IO.File.Copy(foundfile, IO.Path.Combine(destDir, fileName & "_new" & extension))
        Else
            'pattern not matched
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

The method-call would then be as follows:

```
CopyGFiles("C:\Temp", "C:\Temp\Dest")
```

This should be done inside a [`Try/Catch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/try-catch-finally-statement) as different exceptions can occur when working with files.

```
Try
    CopyGFiles("C:\Temp", "C:\Temp\Dest")
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show("An error occured" + vbCrLf + ex.Message)
End Try
```

Comment: You can also use something like: `dim rgx = new Regex("G[0-9]") dim files = Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.G*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(Function(f) rgx.IsMatch(Path.GetExtension(f))).toList()`. With the option to specify whether to use `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew that I was close to the correct answer on my own, but my method was still terribly flawed.